# How/Why do I find the Hyperplane to Calculate the Volume of $A$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, polar-coordinates

Let 
$A:=\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb R^{3}:x^2+y^2+z^2\leq 2\} \cap \{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb R^{3}:x^2+y^2\leq z\}$

I know that $\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb R^{3}:x^2+y^2+z^2\leq 2\}$ is a sphere with radius $\sqrt{2}$ and

$\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb R^{3}:x^2+y^2\leq z\}$ is a paraboloid.

In the solution to calculate $\lambda^{3}(A)$, we use polar coordinates, namely:

$P(r, \Phi, z)$ where $r > 0, \Phi \in ]0,2\pi[,z\in \mathbb R$

**Problem:** We then attempt to find a space $V$ and set $V:=\{0\}\times \mathbb R_{\geq 0}\times\mathbb R$

It is clear that $V$ is just a "half" of the z-y-plane and it is a subset of a hyperplane in $\mathbb R^{3}$, and therefore it has $\lambda^{3}$ measure $0$. I also know that before using the transformation formula we need to have a diffeomorphism that by construction needs to be surjective.

My question: Why is $V$ supposed to be the space we leave out, surely $V \neq \mathbb R^{3} -A$

So why are we using it?

For more context:

We are using the coordinates $p(r, \theta, z)=(r\cos{\theta}, r\sin{\theta}, z)$

and

$\lambda^{3}(A)=\int_{A}1d\lambda^{3}=\displaystyle{\int}_{[0,1]}\displaystyle{\int}_{[0,2\pi]}\displaystyle{\int}_{[r^{2},\sqrt{2-r^2}]}rdzd\theta dr$

In our classes, we have always, when switching to polar coordinates, had to find a $V$ such that $\lambda^{3}(V)=0$ in order to state

$\displaystyle{\int}_{\mathbb R^{3}}f(x,y,z)dxdxdz = \displaystyle{\int}_{R^{3}-V}f(r\cos{\theta},r\sin{\theta},z)rdzd\theta dr$

But I do not see why is it $\{0\}\times \mathbb R_{\geq 0}\times\mathbb R$ in this case?

Comment: It seems to me you have given one step of a solution and left out all the rest, including the parts that would have explained what transformation formula is used and what is "left out." Perhaps someone can guess what you mean, but I have my doubts that they will.

Comment: @DavidK I've hopefully added some context

Comment: OK, the integral looks fine but I don't see what $V$ has to do with it. The context you added doesn't mention $V$ at all.

Comment: @DavidK I want to know why it is necessary to find a $V$ to exclude in order to state $\int_{\mathbb R^{3}-V}f(x,y,z)dxdydz=\int_{\mathbb R_{\geq 0}}\int_{[0,2\pi]}\int_{[r^2,\sqrt{2-r^2}]}rf(r\cos{\theta},r\sin{\theta},z)dzd\theta dr$ ?

Comment: Clearly if $V$ is defined as you wrote it, then $\int_{R^{3}-V} f = \int_{R^{3}} f,$ for reasons you gave. Something is still missing from the question. I think you will have to ask your instructor about this.